# Dell Precision Tower 5810 usb to VGA headless driver setup

Tags: vga, displayport, adapter, display-driver, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision Tower 5810 and want to connect it to a monitor which has a VGA port.

Here:

[image: Ports]

are the ports available on dell precision pc. As far as I can tell, my only options for a monitor are the diplay ports and the USB 3.0 ports.

I have bought [this](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0602/1850/7429/files/User_Manual_723.pdf?v=1640083976) USB to VGA adapter cable which requires the download of an external driver available from their website. Since I do not have a monitor connected to the PC, I have not been able to download the driver and get the monitor to work in the first place. When I plug the USB to VGA cable in, nothing is detected as expected.

I have tested the driver and verrified that the cable works for connecting the monitor on another PC that I already have set up.

Is there a way to download the driver on the dell precision pc without having access to a monitor? I'm not sure if this is important, but when I obtained this pc, the former user told me that they wiped it, so I am unsure what the sign-in options look like.

Should I instead buy a display port to VGA adapter? Would something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GPMRYNM) likely require the download of a driver as well?

Answer (score 0):

A DisplayPort to VGA adapter will not need a driver, since the DisplayPort
connects directly to the GPU.

The adapter in your link gets excellent reviews, so is a good bet.